# Kotlin property delegation without reflection

Tags: kotlin

I have a class wrapping a data object. And i want to

```
class SomeWrappingClass {

    lateinit var data: SomeDataHolder

    // Want to 'forward' many properties to the data class

    var thing0: String? by data
    var thing1: String? by data
    var thing2: String? by data
}
```

Or more realistically like:

```
var thing0: String? by data.thing0
```

The below functions It can be achieved with, but as I've understood it they use reflections and I want to keep the SomeDataHolder crisp. I haven't tried with the reflections but I see them either becoming large when-statements or the entire class turning into a key-value map.

```
SomeDataHolder {

    operator fun getValue(internationalTransferViewModel: SomeWrappingClass, property: KProperty<*>): String? {
    TODO("not implemented")
    }

    operator fun setValue(internationalTransferViewModel: SomeWrappingClass, property: KProperty<*>, s: String?) {
    TODO("not implemented")
    }
```

So basically is there a shorter way to write this:

```
var thing: String?
    get() = data.thing
    set(value) {
        data.thing = value
    }
```

For now I'm going with exposing the `data` class of `SomeWrappingClass`. Letting callers do `myWrap.data.thing = Thing()`

Is there a way to achieve something like what I'm asking without reflection?

Comment: How about `var thing0: String? by data::thing0` ? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#delegating-to-another-property or does that not work because `data` is `lateinit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can delegate writing get/set by hand, and upvote some related issues:

- [Suboptimal compilation of lazy delegated properties with inline getValue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14513)
- [More flexible delegated property convention](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16997)
- [Support Delegates without KProperty](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17034)